# Swagger codegen java client with OAuth flow

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have used the swagger codegen to generate a client for java with --library resttemplate.

Then I configured the OAuth2RestTemplate with ClientCredentialsResourceDetails, prividing the accessTokenUri, clientSecret, clientId and everything worked like a charm (meaning, I injected the OAuth2RestTemplate into the generated ApiClient and the token was obtained correctly and also was auto-refreshed without any coding).

Now, when I generate a simple java client (not the spring one), looks like I have to code the logic of obtaining the token, passing it to the ApiClient and catching the 401 myself.

I am sure that the ApiClient can be generated somehow to include the OAuth flow with client credentials grant ("application" grant type), so that I wouldn't need to write the logic of dealing with the token myself.

I am using swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.

I have tried the following in the Swagger file:

```
"securityDefinitions": {
    "oauth": {
        "type": "oauth2",
        "tokenUrl": "https://myHost:myPort/token",
        "flow": "application",
        "scopes": {
            "read": "read all"
        }
    }
},
"security": "oauth",
```

But the client is not generated with the OAuth flow with my tokenUrl.

Appreciate if someone can assist me with this issue.

Comment: (Reposting as a comment since it's not an answer) 1) It should be `"security": [ { "oauth": ["read"] } ]`, not `"security": "oauth"`. 2) It might be an issue with the Codegen, e.g. this flow might not be supported for this particular target. I'd suggest [opening an issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues) in the Swagger Codegen repository.